# Is Gnome-Session-Fallback getting updates?

Tags: gnome, 12.10

I am using *gnome-session-fallback*, which fairly resembles GNOME2.

I typed the *gnome-session --version* command and here is the output:

```
$ gnome-session --version

gnome-session 3.6.0
```

My question is: Does that mean that it will get updates and bug fixes in the future or is the fallback session old and obsolete technology?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That output just shows the package version, and nothing else.

To get the idea of the current level of support for the fallback session, consider this:

1. The fallback session maintainer, Vincent Untz, has recently left Gnome to take the position of the OpenSuse chairman.
2. It's been announced, that the fallback mode [will be droped](http://www.vuntz.net/journal/post/2012/11/21/No-fallback-mode-in-GNOME-3.8%2C-future-of-gnome-panel) from Gnome 3.8 onward.

That said, Gnome2 will still be supported, for quite some time, by the distros that default to it, most notably, RHEL and its derivatives (CentOS and Scientific Linux), as well as Debian 6, and, perhaps some other.

The point is, if you have the right hardware and like Gnome2, there is no reason not to use it for a long time to come.

Comment: oh well, gnome-session-fallback is in my opinion the most stable and fast DE I've used. I'll stick with it, even if it doesn't get updated. Thanks for the feedback mike!

Comment: Yep, Gnome2 was pretty good.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the GNOME team is introducing a new Fallback Mode in GNOME 3.8 that looks pretty sweet, actually. :) Also, MATE is basically a rebadged GNOME 2.

If you wanna install GNOME 3.8, including the new Classic mode, to try it out, pull up a terminal type in the following command chain:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3 && apt-get update &&
apt-get upgrade && apt-get install gnome-shell gnome-shell-extensions
```

However you can also give Cinnamon a shot, I used it for a while, before finally settling on (at least for now) MATE, and it's just a gorgeous desktop environment, and highly recommended. In order to install it and try it for yourself, type the command chain below in a terminal

```
sudo-add-apt-repository ppa:gwendal-lebihan-dev/cinnamon-stable &&
apt-get update && apt-get install cinnamon
```

However 13.04 has Cinnamon in the official repos.